# jquery trigger function from out

Tags: jquery

I have the following Jquery function.

I want to know how I can call it from outside the function. There are occasions where I need to run it. I can see how to trigger/call it from inside the function at the bottom but I'm unsure how to from outside of it.

```
$.fn.lazyload = function() {
    var elem = this;

    var lazyload = function(elem) {
        var viewport_height = $(window).height() + 100;
        var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
    }
    lazyload(elem);
    $(window).scroll(function(){lazyload(elem);});
    $(window).resize(function(){lazyload(elem);});
};
```

I've tried the following but they don't work:

```
$.fn.lazyload(elem); 
lazyload(elem);
lazyload();
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) for that:

```
$.fn.lazyload.apply(elem);
```

Assuming `elem` is the element you want the function to work with.